# SQL trigger for replicating actions of an ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: sql, triggers, plpgsql

I am working on a project that requires creating a trigger that basically replicates the actions of an ON DELETE CASCADE clause of a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT. The parameter of interest is "account_number",  referencing relationship is "depositor" and referenced relationship is "account". Basically, when an "account_number" is deleted from "account" table, the trigger is to delete all occurences of that "account_number" in the depositor table ("all" specified since there could be joint accounts with multiple customer_ID's listed in the depositor table with that "account_number".
Seems simple enough and I tried a few approaches that I thought should all work; yet none of them are working - that is, when I delete an "account_number" from the "account" table, the corresponding "account_number"s in the depositor table are not getting deleted (despite not getting any error messages along the way). I tried the trigger funciton a couple ways, with the commented out sections below used in one case and commented out in another case - neither worked. What am I missing?

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Demirci_07_bankTriggerFunction()
            RETURNS TRIGGER
            LANGUAGE plpgsql
            AS
            $$
            /*
                DECLARE
                    acct_no_deleted INTEGER;
            */  
                BEGIN
                /*
                    PERFORM account_number
                    FROM account
                    WHERE account_number = OLD.account_number;
                    
                    DELETE FROM depositor
                    WHERE account_number = acct_no_deleted;
                */
                    DELETE FROM depositor
                    WHERE account_number = OLD.account_number;
                    
                    RETURN OLD;
                END;
            $$;
            
            CREATE TRIGGER Demirci_07_bankTrigger
            AFTER DELETE ON account
            FOR EACH ROW
            EXECUTE PROCEDURE Demirci_07_bankTriggerFunction();
```

Comment: Why do you have a separate procedure when you could just do the deletion in line? Also you should tag this with the correct database. Triggers are usually highly implementation specific.

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: Are you using Postgres?

Comment: Yes, I am using PostgreSQL. Sorry that I didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is an `AFTER DELETE` trigger. You have to remove the dependent rows *before* you delete the referenced row.